# What is the effect of coordinate systems on cluster locations?

Tags: coordinates, cluster-analysis, coordinate-systems

I was wondering to know if I have a dataset with geographic coordinate (long, lat, alt) can I make clustering based on these values?. What if these values are converted into Cartesian coordinates (X,Y,Z) or Radian will there be any differences in clustering ?. Should the result of these approach be the same (gathering nearby points together) ?

Overall, I want to know the effect of different coordinate systems of same points on clustering.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the algorithms you are using.

Some clustering tools like [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/) have support for geodetic distances, so they can work with latitude and longitude just fine.

Try to first decide on the **distance measure** you want to use, not so much on the clustering algorithm or a normalization. Choose distance so that it makes sense for your application, not because you know how to write the code for it.